# Fatal error encountered during command execution while executing Mysql query

Tags: c#, mysql

Fatal error encountered during command execution while executing Mysql query in C#

db.cs

```
 public  static void openconn()
    {
        try
        {

                if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    conn.Open();
                }



        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {

                conn.Dispose();

            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }


        }

    }



    public  static  DataTable selectdata(string select)
    {
        DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
        try
        {

            if (CheckForInternetConnection())
            {
                openconn();
                if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    dbcomm.CommandText = select;
                    tbl.Load(dbcomm.ExecuteReader());
                }


                return tbl;
            }
            else
            {

                return tbl;
            }

        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return tbl;

        }

    }



    public async static  void runq(string sql)
    {


        try
        {

            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                dbcomm.CommandText = sql;
                dbcomm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                addActions(sql);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("خطأ بالاتصال بقاعدة البيانات");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show( ex.Message);;
        }






    }
```

When you call this function, you receive the error message
Fatal error encountered during command execution while executing Mysql query in C#

```
   private void loadcolor()
    {
        try
        {
            if (!this.DesignMode)
            {
                db.openconn();
                DataTable tbl = db.selectdata("select color_no,color_name from color");
                cbxcolor.DataSource = tbl;
                cbxcolor.ValueMember = "color_no";
                cbxcolor.DisplayMember = "color_name";

            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
   `enter code here`////
        }
    }
```

How can I solve this problem?
Where the message shows approximately 90% of the function call command execution

Comment: What is the error message you get from MySQL and/or the exception? Please [edit] your question to include all the error information available.

Comment: The results from dbcomm.ExecuteReader() cannot b used to directly load a DataTable.  You ned to use a DataAdapter like in Derdefull.  Derfdefull code will not work because he is using an SqlDataAdapter while you are using MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
    public DataTable selectdata(string Qry)
    {
        try
        {
        var datatable = new DataTable();
        conn.Open();
        MySqlDataAdapter obj = new MySqlDataAdapter(Qry, conn);
        obj.Fill(datatable);
        conn.Close();
        return datatable;
        }
        catch (MySqlException)
        {
            return new DataTable();
        }
    }
```